# TFS Edit project-level information permission

Tags: tfs, permissions

I'm looking for what specifically the "Edit project-level information" permission allows you to do.  So far I've noticed that by default you need this to add/delete areas & iterations, manage check-in policies, create team work item queries.  What else am I forgetting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This permission is also known as "GENERIC_WRITE" if that helps when searching [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#project_test).  Be careful, though: "Edit server-level permissions" has the same underlying name, but is applied to different objects.

Anyway, you listed:

- Areas & iterations
- Checkin policies
- Team-wide work item queries

The other rights this permission controls include:

- Subscriptions (email or SOAP) on project-level events
- Alter project-level permission ACLs (including GENERIC_WRITE itself)